# React Native - Navigation parameters object is null when navigate through multiple navigators including a SwitchNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Navigation parameters (`this.props.navigation.state.params`) is not null if navigation is directly from caller component to callee component.

> caller > navigator > callee

But it is when navigation is indirect and parent navigator is a `SwitchNavigator`

> caller > parent navigator > child navigator > callee

Parent navigator

```
const App = createSwitchNavigator({
    Caller : {screen : Caller},
    To : {screen : To},
    ...
})
```

Navigation from caller

`this.props.navigation.navigate('To', data)`

If `To` is the callee `Component`, `this.props.navigation.state.params` is fine. It becomes null when `To` is a child navigator like below which lists the callee component as a route

```
const To = createStackNavigator({
    Callee : {screen : Callee},
    ...
})
```

Not happens if parent navigator is a `StackNavigator`

Answer (score 0):

You should check withNavigation options of react-navigation [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)

or you might send navigation as prop to child then you send prop to another from there.

```
 <To navigation={this.props.navigation} />
 <Callee navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Comment: before i give your answer a try, i would like to know. are you positive the callee will receive the parameters from the caller? if you read the question carefully and understand it clearly, it's not navigation that is null. it's the parameters